# Intelligent Way To Create Summary Table Without For Loop In R

Tags: r, for-loop

Good afternoon,

I have a data frame as follows, with a timestamp in the first column, as POSIXlt, and a data value in the second:

```
Date            Data
9/9/13 12:48    0.24
9/12/13 10:26   0.26
9/13/13 13:00   -0.14
9/17/13 11:31   -0.04
9/17/13 15:43   0.04
9/18/13 11:51   -0.04
9/18/13 14:35   -0.08
9/18/13 15:11   -0.08
9/19/13 10:12   -0.08
9/19/13 11:48   -0.16
```

I would like to summarize the data column by day that looks like this:

```
Date    Total For Day
9/9/13      0.24
9/12/13     0.26
9/13/13     -0.14
9/17/13      0   
9/18/13     -0.20
9/19/13     -0.24
```

My initial reaction is to create a for loop as follows:

- Run unique(as.Date(Date Column)) to get a list of all of the dates.
- Loop through this new list by creating a total so long as the current date in the initial data table matches the date from the unique list being checked.
- Once the dates don't match, record the total and repeat for the next date until the list is complete.

9 times out of 10, when I do a for loop in R, there is always a command or method that does it more easily and more efficiently.

Is there a better way than a for loop in this case?

Comment: I think your output is incorrect. `9/17/13` shows up twice and `9/19/13` never shows up and the total for `9/18/13` is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively:

Using `ddply`:

```
 require(plyr)
 ddply(yourData, "Date", summarize, Total_for_day = sum(Data))
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)
yourData %.% group_by(Date) %.% summarize(Total_for_day = sum(Data))
```

Or `tapply`:

```
tapply(X = yourData$Data, INDEX = yourData$Date, FUN = sum)
```

Answer (score 3):

If `dat` is you data:

```
aggregate(dat$Data, list(as.Date(dat$Date)), sum)

##      Group.1     x                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
## 1 2013-09-09  0.24                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
## 2 2013-09-12  0.26                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
## 3 2013-09-13 -0.14                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
## 4 2013-09-17  0.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
## 5 2013-09-18 -0.20                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
## 6 2013-09-19 -0.24
```

data for anyone else:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                                                                                                                                                                               
 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(48L, 26L, 0L, 31L, 43L, 51L, 35L, 11L, 12L,                                                                                                                                                                             
 48L), hour = c(12L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 15L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L                                                                                                                                                                              
 ), mday = c(9L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L),                                                                                                                                                                                
     mon = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), year = c(113L,                                                                                                                                                                          
     113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 113L), wday = c(1L,                                                                                                                                                                      
     4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), yday = c(251L, 254L,                                                                                                                                                                                
     255L, 259L, 259L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 261L, 261L), isdst = c(1L,                                                                                                                                                                           
     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("sec", "min",                                                                                                                                                                           
 "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt",                                                                                                                                                                
 "POSIXt")), Data = c(0.24, 0.26, -0.14, -0.04, 0.04, -0.04, -0.08,                                                                                                                                                                           
 -0.08, -0.08, -0.16)), .Names = c("Date", "Data"), row.names = c(NA,                                                                                                                                                                         
 -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This did the trick with one modification.  The format command kicked back an error: invalid 'trim' argument.  I ran the command as follows instead: aggregate(dat$data, list(as.Date(dat$Date)), sum).

Comment: @user2926358 Using `as.Date` is more concise anyways. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `dplyr` for this kind of operations. Your example is not reproducible, I'll use the builtin `mtcars` dataset. The following calculates the mean mile per gallon for each unique cylinder size:

```
library(dplyr)
summarise(group_by(mtcars, cyl), mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  cyl mean_mpg
1   8 15.10000
2   4 26.66364
3   6 19.74286
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I've seen this library mentioned but I have not had any experience with it.  I will look into it as it appears to be very useful.